# How can I display the real number instead of notation? (Using float as a data type)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, type-conversion, notation

[image: View of Details Page]

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
     <label>Gross Selling Price</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
     <p>@Model.GrossSellingPrice</p>
</div>
```

My HTML code for display.

The Gross Selling Price is in Notation which should be in numbers.

Comment: What the datatype of @Model.GrossSellingPrice? And what's the value you are trying to display?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Hi, this is the actual data in database "1234567954432" and the datatype is float. And when I am displaying it becomes a notation.

Comment: @Model.GrossSellingPrice.ToString()

Comment: Since you can't put `1234567954432` into `float` without loosing precision could you please clarify what exactly you expect to see as result?

Comment: @Atk Why do you expect your suggestion to behave differently that `.ToString()` call already performed at render time?